# How to access the Event Object in focusout Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events, jquery-focusout

Sorry to ask such elementary question. I am learning Javascript and jQuery.

I have a popup with 3 input fields say ETD, ETA and duration. I am trying to calculate duration on focusout from ETD and ETA and there will be an AjaxCall in which we do the calculation and other stuff.
The issue is whenever I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key(focusing out of ETD or ETA) the focus will be moved out of popup and will moved to main window.

I am trying to set focus forcefully on these input fields on success of ajax call.
I am trying to achieve this using flags, for example if focusout happened on ETD then ETDFlag will be true and I'll check this flag on `onsuccess` of ajax call, so if ETDFlag is true I'll put focus on ETA and so on,
but the issue is even if I focusout of the field by clicking out of field the focus will go to next field, so I need to set flags only when <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key is pressed.

Below is the sample code:

```
$("#ETD").focusout( function (event) {  
    var keyCode=event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(keyCode == 9){
        ETD= true;
        ETA= false;
    }       
    calculateDuration();
```

I am not getting the event object inside as when I tried `alert(event);` the output was `[object Object]`.

But something like:

> alert(e.target.id)

Will show the id of the field. e.g. ETD

Please help and tell me what is wrong. I am new in Javascript so not able to understand.

## Edited for more clarification

The goal is to go to the next input when user presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button. As mentioned current behaviour is after pressing tab (focusout)  an ajax call will happen to calculate the duration field value and focus will move out of popup to main window!
So the main purpose of having event object is to get the keycode of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button:

```
 var keyCode=event.keyCode || event.which;
 If(keyCode==9)   //tab key code
 {Then make some flag true}
```

But on press of <kbd>Tab</kbd> key it never come inside if condition!

## Edited for more clarification 2

```
var keyCode=event.keyCode || event.which;
```

I tried to use above code on a keyup event and "**keyCode**" is able to capture almost all the keys **except Tab keys**!

Comment: You already got it. you can say `alert(event.target.id)`

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @SLakes add note for clarification

Comment: @andrex : added notes for more clarification, the goal of having event object is to make the tab issue solved

Comment: @SohailAnwer your question was about access event  object.  You are already accessing it my friend.   And for calling ajax put it inside you if condition you alreadygot everything so what is wrong then?

Comment: @andrex : in short I am unable to handle tab key...I want to do some operation on Tab key press .
following code is not working:
    var keyCode=event.keyCode || event.which;
    If(keyCode==9)   //tab key code

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the event object.

`alert()` will convert its argument to a string.
jQuery's `event` object does not override `toString()`, so you get the default of `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need keyup or keydown and not focusout then you do your process.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#ETD").bind('keydown', function (event) {  
      if(event.keyCode == 9){
          alert('its a tab');
          // you do your process here
      }       
   });
});
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oLj9fz8v/1/)**

**Focusout is not a keyboard events** so you can't get any keycode from it.
Read more about **[keyboard events here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)**

Comment: well, I know it is working for keyup and keydown evets, but why not for focusout!!?